# Python: given list of columns and list of values, return subset of dataframe that meets all criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['Bob','Jean','Sally','Sue'], 'B' : [1,2,3, 2],'C' : [7,8,9,8] })
```

Assume that column A will always in the dataframe but sometimes the could be column B, column B and C, or multiple number of columns.

I have created a code to save the columns names (other than A) in a list as well as the unique permutations of the values in the other columns into a list.  For instance, in this example, we have columns B and C saved into columns:

```
col = ['B','C']
```

The permutations in the simple df are 1,7; 2,8; 3,9.  For simplicity assume one permutation is saved as follows:

```
permutation = [2,8]
```

How do I select the entire rows (and only those) that equal that permutation?

Right now, I am using:

```
a[a[col].isin(permutation)]
```

Unfortunately, I don't get the values in column A.

(I know how to drop those values that are NaN later.  BuT How should I do this to keep it dynamic? Sometimes there will be multiple columns.  (Ultimately, I'll run through a loop and save the different iterations) based upon multiple permutations in the columns other than A.

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: I actually did it a slightly different way.  Because the dataframes that I will feed into my script will be different sizes (3-6 columns), I had to be sure  that the solution worked regardless of the size of columns and permutation.  I'm posting my solution below....

Comment: If that's a constraint, you should have put it in your question.

Comment: ^^ "Pretend that column A will always in the dataframe but sometimes the[re] could be column B, column B and C, or multiple number of columns."  Perhaps that wasn't clear enough.

Comment: I have addressed that constraint, but the answer you accepted only works when columns are numeric, and doesn't work with your code, whereas my solution is far more robust. It doesn't seem to me that that you are actually running any of this code. I've been the most critical, but I've also been the only one to upvote this.

Comment: The other solution worked better but thank you for your help. “It is amazing what you can accomplish if you do not care who gets the credit.” 
― Harry Truman

Comment: It worked better, but doesn't work with the code sample you gave? I'm disappointed - someone with an MBA should know better. My plus one is now a minus one.

Comment: Technically I don't have an MBA yet so rest easy ;) ...(P.S. I will never keep up w/ you comp sci bros)....listen you are super helpful..modified this for my project and good to go...obv you're a killer programmer, great suggestions, help, advice etc.  I don't need plus ones or minuses here, just the answers, which I received.  thanks again...I'll be posting more to limp along on my proj!

Comment: Others are supposed to benefit from the questions and answers on StackOverflow. Selfishly running off after you get the particular answer you were looking for that didn't match up with your question is *not* what this site is about. Others who see this will downvote the accepted answer because it didn't match the question or work with the code you supplied, and will probably downvote you for accepting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution.  Aaron's above works well if I only have two columns.  I need a solution that works regardless of the size of the df (as size will be 3-7 columns).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['Bob','Jean','Sally','Sue'], 'B' : [1,2,3, 2],'C' : [7,8,9,8] })
permutation = [2,8]
col = ['B','C']
interim = df[col].isin(permutation)
df[df.index.isin(interim[(interim != 0).all(1)].index)]
```

Comment: I don't think that actually works. It returns a different result. I think you're quite confused.

Answer (score 1):

Use the intersection of boolean series (where both conditions are true) - first setup code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['Bob','Jean','Sally','Sue'], 'B' : [1,2,3, 2],'C' : [7,8,9,8] })
col = ['B','C']
permutation = [2,8]
```

And here's the solution for this limited example:

```
>>> df[(df[col[0]] == permutation[0]) & (df[col[1]] == permutation[1])]
      A  B  C
1  Jean  2  8
3   Sue  2  8
```

To break that down:

```
>>> b, c = col
>>> per_b, per_c = permutation
>>> column_b_matches = df[b] == per_b
>>> column_c_matches = df[c] == per_c
>>> intersection = column_b_matches & column_c_matches
>>> df[intersection]
      A  B  C
1  Jean  2  8
3   Sue  2  8
```

## Additional columns and values

To take any number of columns and values, I would create a function:

```
def select_rows(df, columns, values):
    if not columns or not values:
        raise Exception('must pass columns and values')
    if len(columns) != len(values):
        raise Exception('columns and values must be same length')
    intersection = True
    for c, v in zip(columns, values):
        intersection &= df[c] == v
    return df[intersection]
```

and to use it:

```
>>> select_rows(df, col, permutation)
      A  B  C
1  Jean  2  8
3   Sue  2  8
```

Or you can coerce the permutation to an array and accomplish this with a single comparison, assuming numeric values:

```
import numpy as np

def select_rows(df, columns, values):
    return df[(df[col] == np.array(values)).all(axis=1)]
```

**But this does not work with your code sample as given**

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way:

```
In [77]: permutation = np.array([0,2,2])

In [78]: col
Out[78]: ['a', 'b', 'c']

In [79]: df.loc[(df[col] == permutation).all(axis=1)]
Out[79]:
    a  b  c
10  0  2  2
15  0  2  2
16  0  2  2
```

your solution will not always work properly:

sample DF:

```
In [71]: df
Out[71]:
    a  b  c
0   0  2  1
1   1  1  1
2   0  1  2
3   2  0  1
4   0  1  0
5   2  0  0
6   2  0  0
7   0  1  0
8   2  1  0
9   0  0  0
10  0  2  2
11  1  0  1
12  2  1  1
13  1  0  0
14  2  1  0
15  0  2  2
16  0  2  2
17  1  0  2
18  0  1  1
19  1  2  0

In [67]: col = ['a','b','c']

In [68]: permutation = [0,2,2]

In [69]: interim = df[col].isin(permutation)
```

pay attention at the result:

```
In [70]: df[df.index.isin(interim[(interim != 0).all(1)].index)]
Out[70]:
    a  b  c
5   2  0  0
6   2  0  0
9   0  0  0
10  0  2  2
15  0  2  2
16  0  2  2
```